# What are the different rarity colors in Dead Island?

Tags: dead-island

So far in Dead Island I've noticed white, green, blue, and purple items. These seem to indicate different rarities, similar to the classification system used in Borderlands, but I don't know what these colors actually mean. Is green more rare than blue? What are the different rarity colors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far, here are all the colors I've found ordered in quality (based on overall stats when compared to one of lesser color and also how often I see weapons of that color):

white->green->blue->purple->orange

The in game text during loading says that some of the quest rewards gives you unique weapons, and (assuming Gabriel's Sledgehammer is a unique), it is still an orange colored weapon.  So I'm going to assume that even unique weapons are orange.  I've also found a Master Chef, which was also orange.

[This link](http://www.g4tv.com/thefeed/blog/post/716093/dead-island-weaponsmods-location-guide/) seems to back up my answer.

Comment: So in other words, the exact order as WoW :P

Comment: @Nick T if that's the case, then might we expect beige as either "better" than orange, or as an alternate green/blue? (Heirloom items!)

Comment: I know that "The Ripper," a prize for pre-ordering is unique. I'll insert my code later and update you with what color it is. :D

Comment: the ripper is a mod, the colour depends on the weapon you use it on. Eg. blue rarity baseball bat + duct tape x2, wire x2, belt, large battery, circular blade, metal scrap x2 = blue rarity ripper.

Comment: The orange weapons are the best but the Black Weapons rule I only have have 1 and its a special :D

Comment: There are no black weapons. Also, developer's craft weapons are effectively legendary items despite their white colour rarity. Also, coloured rarity firearms deal damage independent from that listed in their stats.

Answer (score 3):

Orange are the super rare or legendary weapons. Purple are rare, blue and green are rare but tend to be less rare than others.

Answer (score 3):

As Ashley Nunn points out in an [answer to another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/46137/8366), the Dead Island wiki [explains each color in detail](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Item_Rarity):

> There are a total of FIVE different levels of rarity for an item in Dead Island. These are:
>
> - White (Common) - Absolutely everywhere, most items and weapons are this color.
> - Green (Uncommon) - Frequently found in chests and given as a reward from quests. Uncommon items are occasionaly [sic] dropped by zombies on death.
> - Blue (Rare) - Often given as a reward from quests but can be found on zombies after death and in chests although the chance is low.
> - Violet (Unique) - Occasionaly [sic] given as a reward from quests but can be found on zombies after death and in chests but the chance of this is very low.
> - Orange (Legendary) - Rarely given as a rewards from quests and is both rarely dropped by zombies on death and found in chests. Finding one of these is truely [sic] a gem, congratulations if you have one.